# More Stories appears when a user scrolls on a half page

Tags: 7, nodes

More Article Box (More Stories) appears when a user scrolls on a single post at least 400px. The box appears in the right bottom corner and it can show one or more posts related with the current one.

Is there a module like this for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the drupal infinite scroll module with views a try . Then tweak a bit to suit ur needs for scrolling